# Can't resize QEMU VMs

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu

I am trying to increase the size of my QEMU VMs, but I'm running into a problem related to snapshots. For some reason, the **qemu-img** command is showing a snapshot that's been long deleted so the resize command is failing.

Here are the commands I'm running against my Debian 10 VM:

```
$ virsh snapshot-list --domain Debian
 Name                 Creation Time             State
------------------------------------------------------------
```

So it looks like the deletion I made (via **virt-manager**) took. However, **qemu-img** is still showing the snapshot:

```
$ sudo qemu-img info debian.qcow2
image: debian.qcow2
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 50G (53687091200 bytes)
disk size: 18G
cluster_size: 65536
Snapshot list:
ID        TAG                 VM SIZE                DATE       VM CLOCK
1         snapshot1              1.2G 2019-11-09 10:13:13   00:02:09.262
Format specific information:
    compat: 1.1
    lazy refcounts: false
    refcount bits: 16
    corrupt: false
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going back to the `qemu-img` command, I found that doing this worked:

```
sudo qemu-img snapshot -d snapshot1 debian.qcow2
```

I still don't know what the difference between this command and what **virt-manager** does, but at least I've made it past this problem.